# Set install path for autotools and conan based project

Tags: c++, cmake, autotools, conan

I want to set install path for  autotools and conan based c++ project. I am aware of **--prefix** which is passed as an argument. I am looking for a field of AutoToolsBuildEnvironment-typed object equivalent to what we have in CMake **cmake.definitions['CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX']   = 'tempFolder'**

Comment: In CMake the variable [CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) denotes an **absolute path** too. It could be that the file where you set `cmake.definitions['CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX']` is processed in a way which transforms all relative paths to absolute ones. But similar processing could exist for autotools and Conan too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your reply. Is there any variable/environ. variable for auto tools which is equivalent to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX?

Comment: `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is a CMake variable, it has sense only when used in CMake scripts or when passed to `cmake` executable with `-D` option. In Autotools the parameter `--prefix` has the **same meaning**. Not sure what do you asking about.

Comment: @Tsyvarev --prefix is passed as an argument. Instead, I would like to set an environment variable just like cmake.definitions['CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX'] = 'tempFolder'.

Comment: `cmake.definitions['CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX']` is NOT an environment variable. You probably mean `definitions` **field** of `CMake`-typed object in the **Python code** of Conan file. (This object is usually created using `cmake = CMake()`). Do you ask about the field of `AutoToolsBuildEnvironment`-typed object with similar semantic?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, I am looking for a field of AutoToolsBuildEnvironment-typed object with similar semantic

Answer (score 1):

> I am aware of **--prefix** which is passed as an argument.

Good.

> I am looking for an variable equivalent to what we have in CMake **cmake.definitions['CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX'] = 'tempFolder'**

Conan's [`AutoToolsBuildEnvironment`](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/build_helpers/autotools.html) does not provide one, sorry.  Conan's objective with its build helpers appears not to be to provide a uniform, high-level abstraction over various build systems, but rather to provide a close-to-native API for them.  There are advantages and disadvantages to that approach, of course, but the choice is outside your control.

The Autotools are structured differently than CMake is, so it should not be a surprise that Conan's `AutoToolsBuildEnvironment` helper is structured differently than its `CMake` helper. With `AutoToolsBuildEnvironment`, the way to specify a package install prefix is via an argument to the `configure()` method:

```
autotools = AutoToolsBuildEnvironment()
autotools.configure(args=["--prefix=/usr"])
# ...
```

Since you already know about that, you're a step ahead.

If you really, *really* want to be able to set an install prefix via a variable on the build helper, then you can always implement that feature yourself in a subclass of `AutoToolsBuildEnvironment`.

---

### Addendum

Though you expressed in comments on the question that your interest was `AutoToolsBuildEnvironment`, perhaps it would be worthwhile to consider its replacement, [`AutotoolsToolchain`](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/gnu/autotoolstoolchain.html).  The situation here is similar, in that the class provides an API over the Autotools that is pretty closely matched to their CLI, but the details of how it is presented might suit you better.

In particular, `AutotoolsToolchain` instances have a list-valued `configure_args` member in which arguments to the Autotools `configure` script can be set.  By default, it already includes a setting for `--prefix`, but if that is unsuitable then you should be able to append one you like better or, with a bit more effort, to replace the default one.

Comment: In any case, the ``AutoToolsBuildEnvironment`` is deprecated, and it has already a replacement: ``AutotoolsToolchain`` + ``AutotoolsDeps``, that are 2.0-ready, I'd recommend upgrading to those, and reporting in Github if something desired is missing.

Comment: @drodri, the OP confirmed in comments that they were talking specifically about `AutotoolsBuildEnvironment`.  Nevertheless, I added some comments about `AutotoolsToolchain`.

Comment: Yes, sure, I was just trying to raise some awareness to the OP, because these new tools have already been there for many months now, and in a couple of months 2.0 will be released, and it will break if folks haven't upgraded to these new ones.